# many object libraries do not work

Tags: xcode, cocoa, imagekit

I just started learning cocoa programming. I tried to build a simple imageviewer. I created a new project then added a image viewer from the object library. The problem is that I get an error that I can't even find by googling.

```
2012-04-21 20:36:20.620 ImageViewer[2095:403] An uncaught exception was raised
2012-04-21 20:36:20.621 ImageViewer[2095:403] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (IKImageView)
2012-04-21 20:36:20.624 ImageViewer[2095:403] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff83a42fc6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff89dd3d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff83a42dfa +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff83a42d84 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b957729 _decodeObjectBinary + 2714
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b95899a -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1193
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b92f480 -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 486
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b9577bb _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b956ad6 _decodeObject + 201
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8eceac18 -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 1051
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b9577bb _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    11  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b956ad6 _decodeObject + 201
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8eddc106 -[NSWindowTemplate initWithCoder:] + 3998
    13  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b9577bb _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    14  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b95899a -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1193
    15  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b95839b -[NSSet(NSSet) initWithCoder:] + 519
    16  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b9577bb _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b956ad6 _decodeObject + 201
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ebed99d -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 2099
    19  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b9577bb _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    20  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b956ad6 _decodeObject + 201
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ebed048 loadNib + 235
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ebec59c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ebec4b7 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ebec3fa +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ee5f9b3 NSApplicationMain + 398
    26  ImageViewer                         0x00000001087035a2 main + 34
    27  ImageViewer                         0x0000000108703574 start + 52
    28  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

It looks like..I need to link a framework, but cocoa framework has been linked already.

Are there any other things I need to check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack trace is complaining about a missing `IKImageView` class which is part of ImageKit which in turn is part of the Quartz framework.

You will need to add the `Quartz.framework` to the project.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had to choose Caleb's answer since he posted it a little bit earlier.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think his answer is correct. There is no ImageKit.framework that you can add to your project because it is embedded inside the Quartz.framework which is the framework which you will have to add.

Comment: // You're right. Just confirmed that there's no ImageKit framework..reverted. Thank you!

Comment: @mttrb It's a fair point that you add the ImageKit framework to your project by adding the Quartz umbrella framework, but that doesn't change the fact that you *do* in fact add ImageKit to your project. Ht the disclosure triangle next to Quartz in your project and you'll see the ImageKit right there. For the OP: you can tell which framework to add for any class by looking at the "Framework" line at the top of the reference page for the class; if it's part of an umbrella framework as ImageKit is, you'll see that too.

Comment: @caleb Yeah, I realise the distinction you are making but the OP says they are new to Cocoa programming and they would have come straight back and said there is no ImageKit.framework to add.

Answer (score 1):

> -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (IKImageView)

Did you add the ImageKit framework to your project? Your app won't contain the code that defines an IKImageView unless you do.

Comment: Okay..um..a question. How did Xcode allow me to add an object when I didn't have the associated framework? Do I need to find out which framework I need to add every time I add a new object from the library? I think this is a little bit annoying..is there a better solution?

Comment: You just added the object to a .xib or storyboard, which is basically a data file. I suppose it might be nice if Xcode offered to add the related framework to your project for you, but it doesn't. File a bug if you'd find that useful. With a little experience, though, it's not a big issue. You should certainly know what framework an object you're using comes from (the two-letter prefix is usually a strong clue).